# Error can't fetch mysqli_result but fetches it anyways

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I'm working on a small bunch of code, and it fetches the result of the query and prints it out but it also gives me this:

Warning: mysqli_result::fetch_assoc(): Couldn't fetch mysqli_result in /var/www/vhosts/apexfunrun.com/httpdocs/dev/timer.php on line 24

```
    $query = "SELECT field_pep_rally_date_value FROM dr_content_type_school WHERE nid = '$schoolname'";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {    
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $date = $row['field_pep_rally_date_value'];
    $date = str_replace('-', '/', $date);
        echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
        $result->close();
    }
}
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: maybe you should not call         $result->close(); inside your while loop ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `$result->close();` inside the loop.  Move it outside like follows:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {    
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $date = $row['field_pep_rally_date_value'];
    $date = str_replace('-', '/', $date);
    echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));    
  }
  $result->close();
}
```

With the code you have you will definitely see the first `$date` in the result.

Please note that its not really necessary to close these resources as PHP will release them at the end of the script.  It is however a good practice to manually specify them, but not within a loop.